# c# Aforge videoCapture непрерывный захват видео

Tags: c#, aforge

с веб камеры считываю содержимое QR code, данный момент код захватывает первый кадр и считывает, мне нужно беспрерывно захватывать кадр с веб камеры и считывать, как это можно сделать , помогите пожалуйста разобраться

```
private void Reader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

        
        filterinfocollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo filterInfo in filterinfocollection)
            combobox_device.Items.Add(filterInfo.Name);
            combobox_device.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "no camera");
        }
      
    }

    private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterinfocollection[combobox_device.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        captureDevice.NewFrame += CaptureDevice_NewFrame;
        captureDevice.Start();
       timer1.Start();
    }

    private void CaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        pictureBox_Camera.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }

    private void Reader_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (captureDevice.IsRunning)
            captureDevice.Stop();
       
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(pictureBox_Camera.Image != null)
        {
            BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
            Result result = barcodeReader.Decode((Bitmap)pictureBox_Camera.Image);
            if(result != null)
            {
                txt_Qrcode.Text = result.ToString();
               timer1.Stop();
            }
        
        }
    }
```